# Please help me with this translation?

Tags: translation, meaning

What does this translate to in English? Apparently it's a quote.

昨天是歷史, 明天是未知, 而今天是禮物

Answer (score 4):

Don't translate it back, it's translated from English at first.

> The clock is running. Make the most of today. Time
>   waits for no man. Yesterday is history. Tomorrow is a mystery. Today
>   is a gift. That's why it is called the present.

Said by [Alice Morse Earle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Morse_Earle).

Another version:

> Yesterday is history, tomorrow is a mystery, today is God's gift, that's why we call it the present.

Said by [Joan Rivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joan_Rivers).

And it's quoted by the film `Kung Fu Panda`'s dialogue too:

> Yesterday is a history,
>   tomorrow is a mystery,
>   but today is a gift,
>   that is why it is called Present.